# Javascript Client for Light Client Protocol

Tags: light-clients

Is there a Javascript client, even in beta, that implements the [Light Client Protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol) ?

Comment: [LES](https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum/wiki/Light-Ethereum-Subprotocol-%28LES%29) or [PIP](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/The-Parity-Light-Protocol-(PIP))? :)

Comment: `geth` console has javascript client, wouldn't that be enough for you?

Comment: Once I enter in the geth console, which interface should I use to adoperate the light ethereum protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment. Light client still requires substantial amount of data to be downloaded (but much less then full node). There is no current JS implementation yet.